# Create multidimensional array with symfony configuration tree builder

Tags: php, symfony, multidimensional-array, configuration

I want to create a configuration for my own bundle like this:

```
my_filters:
    filter_type_a:
        - \MyBundle\My\ClassA
        - \MyBundle\My\ClassA2
    filter_type_b:
        - \MyBundle\My\ClassB
```

The `my_filters` should be an array of variable length, and the `my_filters.filter_type_a` should be an array of variable length,too.

I tried

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder(); 
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');
$rootNode
     ->children()
         ->arrayNode('my_filters')
             ->prototype('array')
                 ->prototype('array')
                     ->children()
                         ->scalarNode('my_filters')->end()
                      ->end()
                 ->end()
             ->end()
         ->end()
     ->end()
```

but i got the following error: `Invalid type for path "my_bundle.my_filters.filter_type_a.0". Expected array, but got string`.

Here is, where i set the configuration:

```
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $this->loadServices($container);
        $this->loadConfig($configs, $container);
    }

    private function loadConfig(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {       
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $container->setParameter('my_bundle.my_filters', $config['my_filters']);
    }

    private function loadServices(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

I can not see my mistake, can anyone tell me?

Comment: What is your `rootNode`? Change one of your examples to comply each other. Now you have defined `filter_expressions` but provide `my_filters` or `filter_type_a`. It is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. I've added the root node to the sample.

Comment: I think that your mistake in naming. You declare two different nodes with one name `my_filters`

Comment: The error appears, even if i change the name of the inner scalar node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match config

```
my_bundle:
    my_filters:
        filter_type_a:
            - \MyBundle\My\ClassA
            - \MyBundle\My\ClassA2
        filter_type_b:
            - \MyBundle\My\ClassB
```

You need next code in config tree builder:

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');
$rootNode
     ->children()
         ->arrayNode('my_filters')
             ->prototype('array')
                 ->prototype('scalar')->end()
             ->end()
         ->end()
     ->end()
```

Comment: Okay, there is no error, but the parameter 'my_filters' is empty, if i try to read it with `$container->getParameter('my_bundle.my_filters')`.

Comment: Ok. Post your code where you set parameter `my_bundle.my_filters`. I think that problem will be there.

Comment: Post the whole class code. Do you sure that your `loadConfig` is called while container compilation?

Comment: Done. Yes, i'm shure.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? If so try to manually delete all files under `app/cache/`

Comment: Yeah, i've deleted the `app/cache/` folder, but the problem still exists.

Comment: if i use my original code, i can see, that the config is read:
`ArrayNode->normalizeValue(array('my_filters' => array('filter_type_a' => array('\MyBundle\MyClassA')))) in BaseNode.php line 264`, but symfony tells me that he found an `Invalid type` (see my question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78785/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-jagemue).

Comment: this answer should be posted in official symfony documentation ;)